# How to install a router successfully?

Tags: router, ip

I want to install a router (D-LINK DIR-615). I connected one end of the ethernet cable to the internet port on the router and to other end to a port on the Internet Service Provider modem. Then I connected my macbook pro to the router with another ethernet cable.

Then I typed 192.168.0.1 in the browser and I got the d-link install screen. The problem is no matter what I do the "globe" on the router stays red, so I can't get internet connection.

One of the error messages I get is: WAN subnet conflicts with LAN subnet.

What I do during the setup:

1. I choose Internet connection setup wizard and click next.
2. Set a password and click next.
3. Select time zone and click next.
4. I choose static ip adress connection.
5. I enter the ip adress, subnet mask, gateway adress, primary DNS adress, secondary DNS adress and click next.
6. Connect.
7. Reboot now.

But the "globe" on the router stays red.

Comment: Why are you using a static IP? If your modem needs static to the router set that, otherwise use DHCP for your computers and MAC.

Comment: Agreed with @AthomSfere unless you have instructions from your ISP to use static you should use Dhcp.

Comment: I used DHCP now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess your WAN subnet conflicts with LAN subnet ;) It means that you have set up the same subnet both on the modem and router. These are two separate networks and can't work with the same subnet.

Solution: change your router's address from 192.168.0.1 to 192.168.**1**.1 or something like that. You may have to reconfigure your network adapter if it's not using DHCP (and it's probably not if you need a config like that for your modem).

Comment: I changed the 192.168.0.1 to 192.168.1.1 and that solved everything. Thanks